# Permanent mouse freeze in ubuntu 18.04.01

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04.01 alongside windows 10 by dual boot. But in the installation wizard , the mouse cursor freeze and dont work. I am able to continue installation by keyboard.
Also in 'try ubuntu' my mouse dont work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a **bug with your specific mouse** or **Ubuntu version**.

If you search about this, you will see the same as you say and **it happens with** a few many of **random mouses**, computers and versions.

I Recommend you to **try with another version of Ubuntu** or another distribution to find out if the problem isn't your mouse.

Do all options you have in your hard even if it is obvius, because **you can discard what is working** for sure.

It can be very basic, but hardware somethings work wrong. If you have another mouse or you just change the port witch you have the mouse plugged, you know, give a chance to it.

If everything fails, you can **open the terminal** with your working keyboard, pressing `CTRL + ALT + T` to fix it with some way.

Apologizes for not answer at 100% but it can be everything.

*Regards*